# xcode crashes while running program in actual device

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I'm new in iOS development and using xcode 7.2 and swift as programming language. I'm working on integration of Google API to send mail programmatically. When i run project in simulator it works perfectly but if i run it in actual device it throws the error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/GTL.framework/GTL
Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9EC87076-4ACC-464A-AA7F-5133EF51F946/AppName.app/AppName.
```

After changing setting in `Targets->General->Linked Frameworks and Libraries-> GTL.framework -Required` to `Optional`, the error goes out but while running app it crashes with error

```
NSForwarding: warning: object 0xcab20 of class 'GTLServiceGmail' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- did you forget to declare the superclass of 'GTLServiceGmail'?
2016-02-15 23:38:49.579 AppName[675:190073] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0xcab20 of class 'GTLServiceGmail' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector:
```

How to solve this problem? Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears that some object is expected to be of type 'GTLServiceGmail', but isn't, however I'm not entirely sure. Can you upload the code you're using?

Comment: I followed the instruction from "https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift" and used the sample code as mentioned in Step 4: Set up the sample

Comment: I'm having the same error as well, and I followed the sample app exactly.  The error is coming from when I declare   private let service = GTLServiceGmail()

Comment: Hi gbotha, Is that code working for you now?